# Как грамотно завершить работу self hosted wcf службы?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, windows-service

Допустим есть wcf служба, которая хостится в win service.

Если пользователь решит вырубить сервис, то как мне грамотно завершить работу wcf службы?

Допустим, один юзер вызвал метод по перемещению файлов, другой юзер что-то делает с базой.

Если без логики завершить работу Win Service, то это приведет к необратимым последствиям.

Comment: Можно более подробно, как именно хостится WCF служба и кто отвечает за ее работу? Тут такая ситуация - тебе необходимо создать либо блокировки, либо разделяемые ресурсы. Чтобы не завершить сервис преждевременно. Как я думаю навесить проверку перед закрытием, чтобы ничего не было занято и ждать. Если создавать через ServiceHost, то завершать работу через Close. Конкретизируй вопрос, не совсем ясно что и как у тебя будет работать. Добавь кода немного.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галочка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Можно попробовать при остановке Win Service сигналить в WCF Service с помощью `CancellationToken` о том, что Win Service собирается останавливаться. WCF Service внутри себя должен проверять состояние данного `CancellationToken`, и, если запрошена отмена, выдавать исключение для вновь запрашиваемых операций, а уже выполняющиеся, например, прерывать. Win Service должен дождаться завершения отмены активных операций выполняемых WCF Service. Для отслеживания этого в WCF Service можно, к примеру, использовать `ManualResetEvent` и счётчик активных операций.

Ниже примерная реализация (с достаточным числом упрощений).

Контракт:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IWCFService
{
    [OperationContract]
    string Echo(string str);
}
```

WCF Service:

```
public class WCFService : IWCFService
{
    CancellationToken ctOperations;

    public WCFService()
    {
        //у WinService берём CancellationToken остановки операций
        ctOperations = MyService.GetOperationsCancellationToken();
    }

    public string Echo(string str)
    {
        //не выполняем новые операции, если началась остановка
        if (ctOperations.IsCancellationRequested)
            throw new Exception("Service stopping.");

        try
        {
            //увеличиваем счётчик активных операций
            IncActiveCnt();

            //имитация деятельности
            int i = 0;
            while (i++ < 10)
            {
                ctOperations.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
                Thread.Sleep(500);
            }

            return "Echo " + str;
        }
        catch (OperationCanceledException)
        {
            throw new Exception("Service stopping.");
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }
        finally
        {
            //уменьшаем счётчик активных операций
            DecActiveCnt();
        }
    }

    static object lockObj = new object();
    static int activeOperationCnt = 0;
    static ManualResetEvent evtNoActiveOperations = new ManualResetEvent(true);
    //свойство для проверки в WinService
    static public ManualResetEvent NoActiveOperations { get { return evtNoActiveOperations; } }

    private void DecActiveCnt()
    {
        lock (lockObj)
        {
            if (--activeOperationCnt == 0)
                //сигналим, если нет активных операций
                evtNoActiveOperations.Set();
        }
    }

    private void IncActiveCnt()
    {
        lock (lockObj)
        {
            activeOperationCnt++;
            //сбрасываем сигнал, если есть активные операции
            evtNoActiveOperations.Reset();
        }
    }
}
```

Win Service (в данном примере не внешнее приложение, а он сам себе является клиентом WCF Service):

```
public class MyService : ServiceBase
{
    static CancellationTokenSource ctsOperations = null;
    static ServiceHost svcHost = null;

    public MyService() { }

    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        //токен для остановки операций
        ctsOperations = new CancellationTokenSource();

        svcHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(WCFService));
        svcHost.Open();

        //запускаем клиента WCF Service
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(UseWCFService);
        //ждём 13 сек.
        Thread.Sleep(13000);
        //теперь остановим Win Service
        Stop();
    }

    protected override void OnStop()
    {
        //сигналим отмену операций
        ctsOperations.Cancel();

        int msecExtend = 3000;
        RequestAdditionalTime(msecExtend);
        //ждём завершение отмены операций
        WCFService.NoActiveOperations.WaitOne(msecExtend);

        svcHost.Close();
        ctsOperations.Dispose();
    }

    public static CancellationToken GetOperationsCancellationToken()
    {
        return ctsOperations.Token;
    }

    private void UseWCFService(object state)
    {
        //имитируем клиента
        Uri tcpUri = new Uri(@"http://localhost:8733/WCFService/");
        EndpointAddress address = new EndpointAddress(tcpUri);
        BasicHttpBinding binding = new BasicHttpBinding();
        ChannelFactory<IWCFService> f = new ChannelFactory<IWCFService>(binding, address);
        IWCFService svc = f.CreateChannel();

        int i = 0;
        while (!ctsOperations.IsCancellationRequested)
            try
            {
                string echo = svc.Echo((++i).ToString());
                Console.WriteLine(echo);
            }
            catch
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error");
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: Я уже было собирался сам писать ответ :).

Comment: @i-one,У меня вопрос. Допустим у меня N операций, которые может вызывать клиент. Мне проверку на то, что токен не остановлен выполнять нужно в каждом методе или можно как-то обстрагируясь от операции выполнять проверку, когда пользователь что-то дергает?

Comment: @iluxa1810, в тему WCF я всё ещё погружаюсь. Насколько я понял можно обобщить "обвязку" (всё то, что в реализации метода Echo стоит до строчки `int i = 0;` и после `return`), добавив соответствующий `IOperationInvoker` ([пример](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/carlosfigueira/2011/05/16/wcf-extensibility-ioperationinvoker/)), однако от проверки состояния `CancellationToken` внутри метода никуда не деться (как часто его проверять и в каких местах кода - это всегда на усмотрение вызываемого кода, и должно быть подчинено его логике).

Comment: @i-one, а событий никаких нету? Просто, получается, что я после каждого метода должен делать ctOperations.ThrowIfCancellationRequested(), что не правильно.

Comment: @iluxa1810, посмотрите пример по ссылке, там смысл как раз в том, что нужные проверки и действия можно вынести, чтобы они выполнялись в одном месте (в классе, наследуемом от `IOperationInvoker`), только это делается не через события, а через атрибуты. Создаётся атрибут, наследуемый от `IOperationBehavior`, который задаёт, что при выполнении операции должен использоваться определённый Invoker (наш, с нужным поведением). Затем этот атрибут можно назначить всем операциям (или, если хочется, только конкретным). Т.е. создаётся своеобразная "прослойка".

Answer (score 4):

Немножко обобщу и дополню ответ @i-one. Для того чтобы корректно завершать сервис, нужно две вещи:

- уметь сообщать нужному коду о том, что пора закругляться
- дожидаться пока этот код завершит свое исполнение

Сигнализировать о сообщении можно разными способами, самый разумный -- `CancellationToken`, который при старте передается всему необходимому коду.

Дожидаться завершения исполнения тоже можно разными способами. В случае с потоками/синхронным исполнением -- @i-one привел рецепт.

В случае если приложение полностью асинхронное (с использованием `async/await`), в винсервисе на запуске запоминается таск, а на стопе этот таск await'ится.

Еще один момент, который стоит упомянуть: по умолчанию, Service Console Manager выделяет 30 секунд на то, чтобы сервис завершился (если это значение не было переопределено в реестре). Если сервис не уложился в отведенное время, то в консоли он помечается как остановленный, но процесс при этом продолжает работать, что не очень корректно. Если корректное завершение требует много времени, то можно запросить дополнительное время -- вплоть до 125 секунд в сумме:

```
protected override void OnStop()
{
    int timeout = 10000;
    while (!mainTask.Wait(timeout))
    {
        RequestAdditionalTime(timeout);
    }
}
```

Однако в любом случае полезно иметь некий общий таймаут (например, 120 секунд) и завершать работу принудительно (если вдруг какой-то код завис).